# Updating each row with some values of another row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I would like to write an update query in SQL like the following:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.PARENT_ID = [ID of another row]
FROM MY_TABLE AS A
```

What I want to do is, for each row that this update will be applied, I want it to calculate the part `[ID of another row]` from a query like the following:

```
SELECT A.NAME, B.NAME, MAX(B.ID)
FROM MY_TABLE A, MY_TABLE B
WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME
```

So basically:

1. When it is updating a row, it will try to find the other rows that has the same name as the current row being updated.
2. Amongst them, it will try to get the row that has the highest `ID`.
3. And then it will update the `PARENT_ID` value of the current row being updated, to the `ID` value of the row it finds.

What is a way to do something like that in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try INNER JOIN UPDATE:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.PARENT_ID = B.mx
FROM MY_TABLE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT C.PARENT_ID mx, MAX(C.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY C.NAME)
            FROM MY_TABLE C
)B 
ON A.PARENT_ID=B.PARENT_ID
```

provided `PARENT_ID` is unique.

Answer (score 3):

So, every row with the same `Name` should have the same `ParentID`, and that should be the highest assigned ID value for that name?

This should do:

```
;with Highest as (
    select ID,Name,ParentID,MAX(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) as NewParentID
    from MY_TABLE
)
update Highest set ParentID = NewParentID
```

Further reading:

- [`OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [`UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177523%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

How about?:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.PARENT_ID = (SELECT MAX(B.ID)
           FROM MY_TABLE B
           WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME)
FROM MY_TABLE AS A
```